# Measure the width of an AttributedString in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, fontmetrics

I'm writing code against the Java [Personal Basis Profile](http://java.sun.com/products/personalbasis/) in J2ME. I need to measure the width of an [AttributedString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/AttributedString.html) in pixels.

In Java SE, I'd get an [AttributedCharacterIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/AttributedCharacterIterator.html) from my AttributedString and pass it to [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html)#getStringBounds, but in J2ME PBP, FontMetrics doesn't have a `getStringBounds` method, or any other method that accepts a CharacterIterator.

What do I do?

Comment: I should add: what I really need to do is wrap the AttributedString into lines. That'd be a lot easier with a LineBreakMeasurer, which I also don't have in J2ME PBP. :-(

Comment: Which the component uses to display user interface? Canvas or LCD UI (Form, Alert, List...)? Could you attach a picture to better understand?

Answer (score 3):

I struggled really hard with this. I needed to resize a panel to the width of an AttributedString. My solution is:

```
double GetWidthOfAttributedString(Graphics2D graphics2D, AttributedString attributedString) {
    AttributedCharacterIterator characterIterator = attributedString.getIterator();
    FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = graphics2D.getFontRenderContext();
    LineBreakMeasurer lbm = new LineBreakMeasurer(characterIterator, fontRenderContext);
    TextLayout textLayout = lbm.nextLayout(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return textLayout.getBounds().getWidth();
}
```

It uses the **LineBreakMeasurer** to find a TextLayout for the string, and then simply checks the with of the TextLayout. (The wrapping width is set to Integer.MAX_VALUE, so texts wider than that will be cut off).

Answer (score -1):

You **can find the width** of the text in pixels.

```
String text = "Hello world";
int widthOfText = fontObject.charsWidth(text.toCharArray(), 0, text.length());
```

Now, you will have the width of text in pixels in the variable **widthOfText**;

Comment: That won't give you the width of an AttributedString, where part of the string is bold/italic, which is what my question was about. (Bold/italic characters are often wider than their normal counterparts.)